# Are PDF headers all the same regardless of version

Tags: php, apache, validation, pdf, header

I am validating a PDF upload via the header info. I have outputted the header portion that i need to check and that return value is  %PDF-1.4

I know there are several ways to do this, i can use strpos or i can use substr to pull 0 thru 3 and check for %PDF to validate it.

My question is do all PDF file headers contain %PDF within the first 7 positions. I am pulling 7 because i need the extra to also check for other file types i am validating.

Is %PDF version specific or is that global?  I know i could just use strpos for PDF but if i can be more specific then my validation will be more valid.  Actually if all of them were %PDF-1 that would be more specific as well and more valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is do all PDF file headers contain %PDF within the first 7 positions

Yes, they do. The first 4 characters are always `%PDF` as of PDF version 1.7, and this seems unlikely to change in the future. Refer to section 3.4.1 of the [PDF Format Specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) document (page 92):

> The first line of a PDF file is a header identifying the version of the PDF specification to which the file conforms. For a file
>   conforming to PDF 1.7, the header should be
>
> %PDF−1.7
>
> However, since any file conforming to an earlier version of PDF also
>   conforms to version 1.7, an application that processes PDF 1.7 can
>   also accept files with any of the following headers:
>
> %PDF−1.0
>
> %PDF−1.1
>
> %PDF−1.2
>
> %PDF−1.3
>
> %PDF−1.4
>
> %PDF−1.5
>
> %PDF−1.6

Comment: Thanks for the reply and thanks for the doc link as well ;) i have bookmarked that page for future reference.  :)

Comment: @dave if an answer helps you, you might want to accept and/or upvote it using the controls at the upper left of the answer.

Comment: sorry i did not know about doing that... thanks i will do that now :)